# Failing to install anything

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

So everything was fine until i used katoolin to install kali scripts on ubuntu, now when i `sudo apt-get install`, i get the error message telling me

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

However when i run the `apt-get -f install` command, i get another error message,

```
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gconf-service_3.2.6-3_amd64.deb
```

Im still relatively new to linux, and im hoping this is a simple fix, can anyone give me a heads up on how to fix this?

Comment: Please post the *full output* of `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for any 'kali' sources in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` by `grep kali /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` and if you find anything, remove it. After this update your apt again, and your problem should be fixed.

Thank you